# What is the standard way to log a program in C?

Tags: c, c99

Programs in C that have --verbose or --debug option, how they actually implement it? Without using 3rd party libraries.

My goal is not to do this all the time:

```
if(debug) printf("Debug msg\n");
printf("Info msg\n");
```

Comment: You can wrap that in a function or macro (depending on if you need zero-cost debug output or not, but you'll have separate debug binaries in this case...)

Comment: There is no standard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer the below program where a macro is defined and based on the option passed to the executable logging is enabled.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define STREQ(a, b) !(strcmp((a), (b)))
    #define logmsg(fmt, ...) \
        do { \
            if (debug) \
            printf(fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__);\
        }while(0)
    char debug;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
        if (argc > 1) {
            if ( STREQ(argv[1], "debug"))
                debug = 1;
        }

        logmsg("%s\n", "hello_world");

        return 0;
    }
```

Pass `debug as the first argument to the executable to enable logging`

Note : This program has been tested `on Linux with gcc compiler`

Comment: Keep in mind the ## before the __VA_ARGS__ is a GNU extension.

Comment: @epicbrew : Yeah , thanks. Added that as the note in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

The most common I've seen is to print to `stderr`.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUG_MESSAGE(fmt, ...) fprintf(stderr, fmt ## "\n", __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DEBUG_MESSAGE(fmt, ...)
#endif
```

Elsewhere...

```
DEBUG_MESSAGE("VERBOSE: %s", "This is a verbose message.");
```

**EDIT**

Something that would work at runtime:

```
#define DEBUG_MESSAGE(fmt, ...)\
do{\
    if(g_debugEnabled) fprintf(stderr, fmt ## "\n", __VA_ARGS__);\
}while(0)
```

Which can be used similarly.

**LAST EDIT**

Changed to use arbitrary format string with `__VA_ARGS__`.

Comment: This type of logging can't be changed at runtime, like when `./exe --debug` option is not passed to the executable at the runtime.

Comment: The way I've handled that is to distribute a debug library along with beta builds. The application loads the debug version if a flag is specified.

Comment: @defube That's not what OP asked for.

Comment: @SantoshA Fixed again!